# SWIG - Handling TLV(Zero Length Array)

Tags: python, swig

How to handle TLV(type, length, value) structures in SWIG(C and Python)?

```
typedef TLV {
   int type;
   int length;
   int value[0];
} TLV;
```

SWIG thinks this structure has 0 elements and generates the following code.

```
for (; ii < (size_t)0; ++ii) arg1->value[ii] = arg2[ii];
```

How do I override this behavior?
I am trying to figure out a way to access TLV->length in

```
%typemap(memberin) int value[0] {
}
```

Comment: I've found it much easier to just pass/return `PyObject *` to/from C/C++ code and do whatever conversions necessary in the code and not in the SWIG interface file, using the methods here:  https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/concrete.html

Comment: I am doing the similar method of manual binding between python and C which become a burden for a huge code base. So I am looking for automated way.

Comment: The problem with a SWIG `%typemap` is you have to write pretty much the same translation code anyway. See SWIG's own example: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn59  What's the point of that?

Comment: Correct - I can write typemap or manual translation for one special structure like this which SWIG automatically cant handle. However still want to stick with SWIG for remaining structures and functions - so prefer typemap if possible.